# .net iis cannot load file assembly

Tags: .net, web-config, iis-7.5, .net-assembly

Searched and found many results and tried everything but couldnt figure it out!

Created an app in VS 2008 and published to an existing iis6 server and works fine.
We just got a new Windows 2008 RC2 server with iis7.5 and when I publish there I get this error (on the local machine)

[image]

I installed the AJAX Libs and toolkit also tried adding things to the web.config.

I can provide any necessary information.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to install .NET 3.5. IT's not by default.
This is as per: http://forums.iis.net/p/1162980/1926330.aspx

Verify this one and if already installed, check the application pool whether it's .NET 2.0 integrated mode

Start with these and leave a comment on this answer if the problem still exists to try to give  more solutions.